# Send picture as string and decode

Tags: python, decode

I have client with Python2.7 and app hasn't opportunity to send files to server.
So I send picture as string.

```
with open(path, "rb") as imageFile:
        str = b64encode(imageFile.read())
```

And on server I try to decode and It fails

```
pic = request.POST.get('picture')
pic = bytes(pic)
fh = open("d:/imageToSave.jpg", "wb")
fh.write(pic)
fh.close()
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I what way does it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decode the string first, then write. As I tried, the type convertion 'bytes(pic)' is not necessary

```
pic = request.POST.get('picture')
pic_decode = base64.b64decode(pic)
fh = open("d:/imageToSave.jpg", "wb")
fh.write(pic_decode)
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

your **encode decode Code** is working but on server i think you should be give a **777 writable permission on folder** i am sure using this your problem will fix.

Comment: File was created,but I cann't see It as image @axit

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you will do in python but you can pretty well try this technique of converting the image/picture to byte_code in a string array and then send the data.

Warning the hexadecimal code is pretty lengthy even for small sized(low grade) image.